# Read file for search for the computer you are going to install the software and to get its index

Tags: java, file, search, arraylist

I want to search for the computer on which you are going to install the software and to get its index.  Then I want to find the index of the software that you want install on the computer based on the searched code.  Finally, use the computer and software indexes and call the appropriate method to install the software on the computer.

How can I find the index of the software to install on the computer, based on the searched code and use the computer and software indexes to then call the appropriate method to install the software on the computer?

```
mypen = new PrintWriter(output);

ArrayList<Component>all=new ArrayList();

while(input.hasNext()){
  String choice = input.next();
  if (choice.equals("Add_Computer") ){

    String ignoreword =input.next();
    String modelName =input.next();
    double speed =input.nextDouble();
    String CompanyName=input.next();
    String code =input.next();
    Computer computer;
    computer = new Computer (modelName,speed,CompanyName);
    all.add( computer);

    for (int i=0;i<all.size();i++){
      if (all.get(i) instanceof Computer){
        Computer c =(Computer)all.get(i);
        String cc =c.getComp_code();
        if (cc.equals(c)){

          int endexOfcomputer=i;
          for (int n=0;n<all.size();n++){
            if (all.get(n) instanceof Software){
              Software s=(Software)all.get(n);
              String ss=s.SetSoft_Code(); //error 
              if (ss.equals(s)){
                int endexOfSoftwer=n;
                mypen.println((Software)all.get(n).ss.SetSoft_Code() //error 
                    .all.get(endexOfcomputer).setSoftware(all.get(endexOfSoftwer)); //error 
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**file.txt**

> Add_Computer Dell 4.5 Inspiron-14 c1
>   Add_Computer Fujitsu 5.6 SRS c2
>   Add_Computer Dell 4.4 Inspiron-11 c3
>   Add_Computer Fujitsu 4.6 ESPRIMO-X-Series c4
>   Add_Computer Dell 4.6 Inspiron-15 c5
>   Add_Computer Fujitsu 5.2 ESPRIMO-Y-Series c6
>   Add_Computer Dell 4.7 Inspiron-15-DVD c7
>   Add_Computer Fujitsu 6.6 ESPRIMO-z-Series c8
>   Add_Computer Dell 4.8 Inspiron-13-2-in-1 c9
>   Add_Computer Fujitsu 5.2 ESPRIMO-Y-Series c10
>   Add_Computer Dell 4.9 Inspiron-17 c11
>   Add_Computer Fujitsu 5.6 SRS c12
>   Add_Computer Dell 6.2 INSPIRON-Special-Edition c13
>   Add_Computer Fujitsu 5.6 SRS c14 c15
>   Add_Computer Dell 4.5 Inspiron-14 c16
>   Add_Computer Fujitsu 5.6 SRS c17
>   Add_Computer Dell 4.4 Inspiron-11 c18
>   Add_Computer Fujitsu 4.6 ESPRIMO-X-Series c19
>   Add_Computer Dell 4.6 Inspiron-15 c20
>   Add_Computer Fujitsu 5.2 ESPRIMO-Y-Series c21
>   Add_Computer Dell 4.7 Inspiron-15-DVD c22
>   Add_Computer Fujitsu 6.6 ESPRIMO-z-Series c23
>   Add_Computer Dell 4.8 Inspiron-13-2-in-1 c24
>   Add_Computer Fujitsu 5.2 ESPRIMO-Y-Series c25
>   Add_Computer Dell 4.9 Inspiron-17 c26
>   Add_Computer Fujitsu 5.6 SRS c27
>   Add_Computer Dell 6.2 INSPIRON-Special-Edition c28
>   Add_Computer Fujitsu 5.6 SRS c29
>   Add_Computer Fujitsu 5.6 SRS c30
>   Add_Software Microsoft-Office 2015 s1
>   Add_Software Kasper-Sky-Antivirus 2015 s2
>   Add_Software Microsoft-Visio 2015 s3
>   Add_Software Microsoft-Visual_Studio.net 2015 s4
>   Add_Software Mysql 5.624 s5
>   Add_Software NetBeans-IDE 8.2 s6
>   Add_Software Adobe-Dreamweaver 2015 s7
>   Add_Software Adobe-Reader 11.10 s8
>   Add_Software Adobe-Photoshop 2015 s9
>   Add_Software MSSQL-Server 2015 s10
>   Install_SW c1 s1
>   Install_SW c1 s2
>   Install_SW c1 s3
>   Install_SW c1 s4
>   Install_SW c1 s8
>   Install_SW c1 s9
>   Install_SW c1 s10
>   Install_SW c2 s3
>   Install_SW c2 s4
>   Install_SW c2 s5
>   Install_SW c2 s6
>   Install_SW c2 s7
>   Install_SW c2 s8
>   Install_SW c2 s9
>   Install_SW c3 s4
>   Install_SW c3 s6
>   Install_SW c3 s7
>   Install_SW c3 s8
>   Install_SW c3 s9
>   Install_SW c3 s10
>   Install_SW c4 s4
>   Install_SW c4 s6
>   Install_SW c4 s7
>   Install_SW c4 s8
>   Install_SW c4 s9
>   Install_SW c4 s10
>   Install_SW c5 s4
>   Install_SW c5 s6
>   Install_SW c5 s7
>   Install_SW c5 s8
>   Install_SW c5 s9
>   Install_SW c5 s10
>   Install_SW c6 s4
>   Install_SW c6 s5
>   Install_SW c6 s7
>   Install_SW c6 s8
>   Install_SW c6 s9
>   Install_SW c6 s10
>   Install_SW c7 s1
>   Install_SW c7 s2
>   Install_SW c7 s3
>   Install_SW c7 s5
>   Install_SW c7 s8
>   Install_SW c7 s9
>   Install_SW c7 s10
>   Install_SW c8 s1
>   Install_SW c8 s2
>   Install_SW c8 s7
>   Install_SW c8 s8
>   Install_SW c8 s9
>   Install_SW c8 s10
>   Install_SW c9 s2
>   Install_SW c9 s4
>   Install_SW c9 s6
>   Install_SW c9 s8
>   Install_SW c9 s9
>   Install_SW c9 s10

Comment: What is the error you're receiving?  Do you have a stack trace to share?  It looks like you're trying to call `SetSoft_Code()` on the string `ss`.  What does `SetSoft_Code()` return (you're also trying to set `ss` to that earlier on in the code)?